# Snapshot of records each month and ability to report on the same

Tags: apex, reporting

We have a custom object, records are created and updated on daily basis.
Below is our requirement:
1] Take a snapshot of all these records on day 1 of the month and store it (as same custom object records, or as new custom object records, or as CSV, to external system etc.).
2] Similarly take the snapshots for every month.
3] There should be provision to view any of the snapshot and report on the same.

What will be the better approach for the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [Analytic Snapshot](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_setting_up_analytic_snap.htm&language=en_US&type=0) to schedule regular reports that will be exported to a separate object, which you can then report on as you'd like. Basically, you create a new object with custom fields, then create a report, and then set up an analytic snapshot.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The custom object currently have around 45,000 records and will keep on increasing. Does that will have any impact on the Analytic snapshot?

Comment: @AmeyB There' a 2k limit, which is good for summaries, but if you want to literally back up all 45k records, you'll need to write your own scheduled/batch process to copy the records.